# Is there an inequality to compare the essential supremum of a function to the function itself?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, supremum-and-infimum

Consider any measurable function $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R.$ It is well known that $\sup f \geqslant f(x),$ for every $x \in \Omega$ (the supremum must be an upper bound). I was wondering: is there an analogue of this inequality using $\text{ ess $\sup$ }$ instead of $\sup$ ?

Clearly, one can't guarantee that $\text{ ess } \sup f \geqslant f(x),$ for every $x \in \Omega.$ A counter-example follows: consider $\Omega = \Bbb R$ and define

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{ if } x \in \Bbb Z, \\[.2cm] 0 \quad \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

We have that $\text{ess } \sup f = 0,$ but $f(x) = 1, $ for $x \in \Bbb Z.$ Therefore, the inequality can't hold.

So I started wondering: altought the inequality $\text{ ess } \sup f \geqslant f(x),$ for every $x \in \Omega$ doesn't hold, could it be true that

$$ \color{red}{\text{ ess } \sup f \geqslant f(x), \, \, \text{ for almost every } x \in \Omega ?} $$

I couldn't come up with a counter example for this inequality but I also can't show that it holds (note that the precedent example doesn't show this inequality is false since $\Bbb Z$ has measure zero). So, essentially, my goal with this question is to find out where the inequality posted in red is true or false.

Thanks for any help in advance.

---

### UPDATE (formal definition of essential supremum)

The definition I am using for essential supremum is the following:

$$ \text{ ess } \sup f = \inf\{ a \in \Bbb R \, \colon \, |\{x \in \Omega \, \colon \, f(x) > a\}| = 0\}.$$

This can be rewritten as

$$ \inf\{a \in \Bbb R \, \colon \, f(x) \leqslant a, \text{ almost everywhere on } \Omega \}.$$

(note that I denoted $|\cdot|$ as the measure in cause).

Comment: what is your formal definition of essential supremum?

Comment: @Yanko Sorry. Added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it follows that $\text{ess sup} f \geq f(x)$ for almost every $x\in \Omega$.

Indeed, if by contradiction this is false, then there exists a set $A$ of positive measure so that $f(x) > \text{ess sup} f$ for all $x\in A$.

For every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_n = \{ x\in \Omega : f(x) > \text{ess sup f} + \frac{1}{n}\}$, and let $B_n:= A_n \backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$ (exercise: prove that these are measurable sets).

Now $\bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n A_n = A$, because if $f(x)>\text{ess sup} f$, then for some $n$ sufficiently large $f(x)> \text{ess sup} f + \frac{1}{n}$.

Since $B_n$ are disjoint, $\sum_n \mu(B_n) = \mu(A)>0$ and so there exists some $n_0$ so that $\mu(B_{n_0})>0$.

We want to show that this is a contradiction. Since $\text{ess sup} f + \frac{1}{n_0} > \text{ess sup} f$ and by the definition of infimum, we can find some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $\text{ess sup} f + \frac{1}{n_0}\geq a \geq \text{ess sup} f$ so that $\mu(\{x\in \Omega : f(x)>a\})=0$. Since $B_{n_0}\subseteq \{x\in \Omega : f(x)>a\}$, we deduce that $\mu(B_{n_0})=0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood most of it, having only one question: I don't understand the contradiction: more precisely, I don't understand why "by assumption, $\mu(\{ x \in \Omega \, \colon \, f(x) > a \}) = 0$ for all $a > \text{ ess } \sup f$". Can you provide more details on this claim?

Comment: @xyz I made an edit explaining that (It follows from the definition of infimum).